# Ошибка: "Нет перегруженной подпрограммы с такими типами параметров" код не работает, в чем проблема?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
program Hello;
var 
  a, x, b, y :real;
begin
  writeln('Введите b Переменную');
  readln(b);
  writeln('Введите y Переменную');
  readln(y);
  x:=(b*(sqrt(b+y)-(sin(b)/cos(b))/(y+1)));
  a:=((exp(ln(exp))*(0,8*x))+0,8*exp(ln(exp)*(x*y)));
  writeln(x, a);
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

> в чем проблема?

1. `ln(exp)` - это что должно делать?
2. `0,8` - считайте, что Вы в Америке, и пишите `0.8`